# no permission to connect to the WMI provider - after sql server installation

Tags: windows, sql-server, windows-server-2016, wmi, sql-server-2016

I am the administrator of a windows server 2016.
After installing sql server, I want to use the `sql server configuration manager` to have a look at what ports and accounts are there, check if all is ok.

however I get the error message - cannot connect to WMI provider.

[image]

it is a virtual box, but not sure how much it could be related to this.

how can I find who is the WMI provider and get this permission to connect to that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have installed SQL Server 2005 components or you are installing them. Please very verify that on Control Panel -> Programs and Features. SQL Server 2005 is not supported on Windows Server 2016. Please read [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2681562/using-sql-server-in-windows-8-and-later-versions-of-windows-operating) official document to know which versions of SQL Server are supported on Windows Server 2016.

Based on that documentation, the lowest version of SQL Server supported on Windows Server 2016 is SQL Server 2012 with Service Pack 2.

If you have confirmed that you are installing only SQL Server 2012 or later versions of SQL Server then workaround the problem by opening a command prompt, type the following command, and then press ENTER:

```
mofcomp "%programfiles(x86)%\Microsoft SQL Server\number\Shared\sqlmgmproviderxpsp2up.mof"
```

Note For this command to succeed, the Sqlmgmproviderxpsp2up.mof file must be present in the %programfiles(x86)%\Microsoft SQL Server\number\Shared folder.

For more details about this workaround, please read [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/956013/error-message-when-you-open-sql-server-configuration-manager-in-sql-se) support article.

Answer (score 1):

running the following command as [suggested by Alberto Morillo](https://serverfault.com/a/990045/409628) sorted out the problem
and now the sql server configuration manager works as you can see on the picture below.

```
mofcomp "%programfiles(x86)%\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Shared\sqlmgmproviderxpsp2up.mof"
```

[image]
however, the `running under 64 bits os` was set to `no`, and now I have changed it to `yes` and restarted the services.

[image]